# Existem vs existe. Como utilizar corretamente?

Tags: ortografia

Gostaria de saber qual o modo correto de utilizar as palavras "existem" e "existe". Por exemplo, na seguinte frase: "Hoje existem discussões", a palavra está correta ou seria "Hoje existe discussões"?

Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O verbo *existir* é intransitivo (em particular, é inacusativo; o sujeito é um tema, não um agente). O verbo só tem portanto uma posição para preencher, que na voz ativa é o sujeito, logo não há dúvida de que *discussões* é o sujeito. Concordando o verbo em número com o sujeito, a forma correta é *existem discussões*, isto independentemente de o verbo anteceder o sujeito.

O caso seria diferente com o verbo *haver*, já que esse é transitivo direto (mas impessoal). Portanto, *há discussões* e *discussões, há-as*.

Comment: Artefacto pode dar um exemplo do caso do verbo haver para a resposta ficar mais completa?